# why the same font-family dispaly different style under IE and firefox?

Tags: html, css

1. under IE7:
   [ie http://run.xxmn.com/images/ie.jpg](http://run.xxmn.com/images/ie.jpg)
2. under firefox
   [firefox http://run.xxmn.com/images/firefox.jpg](http://run.xxmn.com/images/firefox.jpg)

I made a style on the site like this:

```
* {
       font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
       font-size:14px;
       margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

How to make theme show the same style under IE and Firefox?

Comment: Were the browsers running on the same computer?

Comment: This probably won't make the text 100% the same, but I suggest a CSS reset like the YUI CSS Reset:  http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two examples you show are the same style.  I.e. they have the same font, same spacing, etc.

However, the rendering of each is different.  One is anti-aliased, and the other is not.  This has to do with how the browser renders text and may be affected by browser and system settings.  You cannot control this from css.  If you want text to look *exactly* the same on two browsers/platforms, you will have to make an image.

Comment: +1 for correctness...  however, you don't *have* to make it an image.  There are other ways.  Cufon comes to mind.

Comment: I was not aware of Cufon... and wow, Javascript rendering.  You do lose selectable text just like an image it seems.  Anyway, you learn something every day.

Comment: This is correct, but the reason why IE7 is bolder and blurrier is that IE7+ lets you independently set "ClearType" on outside of the Windows option.  To turn it off, goto `Tools > Options > Advanced > Multimedia > Uncheck "Always use ClearType for HTML"` and re-start IE.

Comment: Yes, ClearType relies on subpixel rendering, so it is callibrated on a per monitor basis.  There is not going to be a programattic solution for that.